# SSIS make LastModifiedProductVersion from 10.50.1600.1 to 10.50.6000.34

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, ssis

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and there was a package  with LastModifiedProductVersion of 10.50.6000.34. I edited the package. I had SQL Server 2008r2. The package changed the  LastModifiedProductVersion to 10.50.1600.1. 
I researched and determined that I would need to apply the SQL Server Service Pack 3 to my SQL Server. I did this and restarted the computer, restarted my SSIS package and rebuilt it but the LastModifiedProductVersion  is still 10.50.1600.1. Does anyone have any ideas how to change my Visual Studio or SQL Server or do something else to change it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Visual Studio/BIDS and in Help, About find SQL Server Integration Services

Does it look like this?

> SQL Server Integration Services
>   Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
>   Version 10.50.6000.34

If so, you have SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 installed on your machine.

As to `LastModifiedProductVersion` that has no bearing in how the package will operate. If you're desperate to make it report the 6000 value, within Visual Studio right click on the package and select View Code. Find the correct node and replace 10.50.1600.1 with 10.50.6000.34

### Addressing comments

From the comments,

> But on my Visual Studio 2008 I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.30729.4462 QFE.

If your SSIS Version starts with 9, you are using the Visual Studio 2005 shell to author SQL Server 2005 SSIS packages.

If your SSIS version starts 10.00, you are using Visual Studio 2008 shell to author SQL Server 2008 SSIS packages.

If your SSIS version starts 10.50, you are using Visual Studio 2008 shell to author SQL Server 2008R2 SSIS packages.

The following screenshot illustrates VS 2005 and SQL Server 2005 on the left and VS 2008 + SQL Server 2008 R2 on the right.

[image]

### Running visual studio

Visual Studio is launched by a executable called `devenv.exe`. Assuming standard install paths, this would leave you with

- (2005) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE
- (2008) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE
- (2012) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
- (2012) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE
- (2014) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE
- (2016/2014/2012) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 13.0\Common7\IDE

Prior to the release of 2016, there was no ability to author backwards compatible SSIS packages, thus if you edited a 2005 package under the 2012 editor, it was forever updated to that version and would no longer run on 2005.

Comment: On my SQL Server 2008r2 I have Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6000.34 (X64) . But on my Visual Studio 2008 I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.30729.4462 QFE. I should add that the menu gave me the option of About Visual Studio not SQL Server Integration Services. Why is the update not reflected in Visual Studio?

Comment: VS 9 is sql server 2005

Comment: How do I get the VS to reflect the SQL Server 2008r2 sp3 that I have installed on my machine? I do not have SQL Server 2005 on my machine.

Comment: You have showed me how to see the SQL Server Integration Services Version. It is 10.50.6000.34 which is what I was after so I will just change LastModifiedProductVersion  manually. I appreciate your help.